# Amazon linux AMI vs Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I was given a project that was running on Amazon linux AMI, now I need to transfer project to Ubuntu server.

I am more familiar with Ubuntu.

I was wondering what would be the difference? Will the project work perfectly on Ubuntu?

Comment: This question does not fall under the scope intended by this website: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Take a look at these users' insights, who also compared it: https://www.quora.com/Which-EC2-instance-is-better-Amazon-Linux-AMI-or-Ubuntu

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/275736/amazon-linux-vs-ubuntu-for-amazon-ec2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amazon Linux AMI is a red hat based distro so things like the package installer or the tools for service manage are different, and another thing you need to consider is the way of bootstraping, amazon instances are more flexible to do some things in cloudformation in the ubuntu way the best form to do it is with cloudinit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit, you need to consider the packages too are multiple packages that not are native supported by Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Linux AMI based on CentOS 6.x, whereas Amazon Linux 2 is CentOS 7.x,

So instead of `apt` you would use `yum`,

and instead of `/usr/local/bin/composer` you'll have to use `/usr/bin/composer`

...